# VBA doesn't accept Dim Variable As

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have used VBA for a long time. But today I started to write some VBA code in Word-VBA and I got the error shown below. It does not accept "Dim variable As ...". I know VBScript doesn't take types, but VBA has to. What is going on?

PS: This is Word 2016

[image]

Comment: hmm .. any difference if you change the name of the variables, or use `Dim Pots&` instead?

Comment: No. No difference,

Comment: Can't reproduce the error. Try rewriting it or even restarting Word and typing it back again. Don't know what else could you do... :)

Comment: I know that this was unbelievable, that is why I added the screenshot. Maybe someone else has run into this, otherwise I am stuck. Tried restarting etc.

Comment: Do you have a sub or function by the name of 'Pots' in your project? Or perhaps a constant or enumeration, not to mention a global variable? Search your project for "Pots" of any description.

Comment: Did you copy/paste this code into the VBA IDE? If so, hidden characters pasted into the variable declaration may have caused the error. I do not think @Variatus has identified the cause because a declaration of Pots in two parts of the code would probably yield an "Ambiguous name detected" error message. Lastly, I do not think the screen cap you provided is from Word 2016. If you look at the second icon from left on the toolbar (Insert UserForm) it is different from the icon that comes with Word 2016. It does match the icon in my version of Word 2010 and may match other versions as well.

Comment: @joeschwa's comment above points to another possible source of the problem. If you are switching between versions of Excel the error could be caused by a missing or incompatible reference. Check the References from the Tools menu.